# Does a polynomial function on spectrum uniquely define polynomial on operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X\subset\mathbb C$ be a compact set, let $T$ be a bounded operator with its spectrum contained in $X$, let $P$ be a polynomial. Is it true that whenever $P=0$ on $X$ then $P(T)=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $$ T=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix},$$ and take $P(x)=x$. You have $\sigma(T)=\{0\}$, $P(0)=0$, but $P(T)\ne 0$.

If we are talking operators on a Hilbert space and $T$ is normal, then the answer is yes, because the spectrum of $P(T)$ is $P(\sigma(T))$ (always) and for a normal operator if the spectrum is $\{0\}$ then the operator is zero.

More than that, similar to a normal would be enough, because neither $P$ nor the spectrum see the conjugation by an invertible.

Comment: so we need $T$ to be diagonalizable ?

Comment: Yes. I expanded the answer a bit.

Comment: it is also highly related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)

Comment: Thanks, it's one of those times when I think I should have thought harder before asking question

Comment: Don't worry. It happens to all of us.